# Why color of mesh does not change (using three.js)?

Tags: colors, three.js, mesh

I am using three.js to create some objects:

```
    // it probably does not matter where geom1 or geom2 comes from
    var materials = [
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { opacity: 0.2, color: 0x000000, transparent:false, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x445555, wireframe: true } )

    ];
    mesh2 = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom2,materials);

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xEEEEEB, transparent:false, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geom1,material);
    mesh1.material.color.setHex( 0xEEEEEB );
```

As you can see from the code I tried creating materials in 2 ways. It does not matter what values I give to color parameters in both cases the color never changes (it is always grey). Unless I adjust opacity then it gets darker or brighter of course. What am I missing here?

Comment: color 0xEEEEEB is gray.. hex is red,green,blue 0xRRGGBB so 0xff0000 is red, `mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geom1,m);` - m is undefined, if you change color of material after it is created set `material.needsUpdate = true`

Comment: Oh, that m. I forgot to change its name to material. `mesh1.material.needsUpdate = true` worked! Thank you @Derte Trdelnik again:). But still: why even after I put '0x33cc33' instead of '0x000000' on my MeshLamberMaterial object mesh2 is still grey while when I changed color to '0x33cc33' in line 'new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x445555, wireframe: true } )' it changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after updating a color outside its declaration, you set the needsUpdate parameter

```
material.needsUpdate = true;
```

since

```
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {  color: 0x33cc33, side: THREE.DoubleSide } )
```

shows as gray/shade of gray you probably dont have any lights in the scene, to add one try

```
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff))
```

or set emissive color of the LambertMaterial

```
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x33cc33, side: THREE.DoubleSide, emissive: 0x33cc33})
```

for it to emit the color

Comment: Strange things.
1) I have SpotLight and AmbientLight present and adding `emissive: 0x33cc33` to the MeshLambertMaterial does not change anything.
2) When I change MeshLambertMaterial to BasicMeshMaterial everything works

You helpd me to see my mistake and solve the problem.